# How can I debug something in IE9 - strange behaviour

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have reported bug, that something doesn't work in IE9. I started IE and I saw that bug, but as soon as I ran developer tools in IE, my bug was gone and everything works well. Unfortunately when I run IE again bug is still.

What is the worst it happens not only for one concrete bug. It happens all the time. So it isn't nature of bug, but IE. It prevents me to debug it. What can I do?

I didn't switch mode of engine in developer tool

Comment: please add more details about the problem

Comment: As I wrote, it isn't concrete bug. For example menu doesn't dropdown in Wordpress and there is a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that there is `console.log(...)` in my code.

Until I don't run developer tools, console doesn't exist and it throws error and my code stops, so rest doesn't work.